# How to cache .js and .css and another static files in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching, pug

i tried a lot, but i cant cache my WebApplication built on Nodejs Express with `JADE` templating engine.

what i tried is,

1- tried `pm2` manager
2- tried setting `NODE_ENV` to `production`
3- added cache module (but i dint understand how to use that)

```
const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
const myCache = new NodeCache( { stdTTL: 100, checkperiod: 120 } );
```

but it didn't cached.

thi is the result from https://nodejs.org/en/
[image]

and this is the result of my web app,
[image]

i need to cache all the static files how to do that .. kindly help me please.. thank you

Comment: Just caching them for 100 seconds? Moreover just instantiating `NodeCache` will not do anything. This may come handy https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/simple-server-side-cache-for-express-js-with-node-js-45ff296ca0f0

Comment: The browser will automatically cache static resources once you are actually hosting it somewhere... Anyways, you shouldn't use node to host static files in production and should use whatever web-server/reverse proxy you use to expose your site/application to the public (nginx/apache/etc). You don't need to use any explicit caching or module in your code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a node based server. For client side caching set proper headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: @nilobarp where to add those codes? i added it on my index.js but not caching. it still fetching all the datas from server

Comment: @AnonymousObject in express route handler before sending the response.

Comment: like this, const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
const myCache = new NodeCache( { stdTTL: 5000, checkperiod: 120 } );
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
??

Answer (score 1):

Set `Cache-Control` headers in `handler` method.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=31536000');
    res.send('hello world');
});
```

There's no need to use `node-cache` for client side caching.

Comment: bro what about res.render('index') ?

Comment: bro but js,css files didn't get cached, max age is 0